# Listing files in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

When i try the below code am getting all files whose filename starts with E

```
#!/bin/bash

data=$(ls -trh E*)
for entry in ${data}
do
  echo ${entry}
done
```

But if i try the below code , which get the wildcard from argument , i am getting only the 
first filename

```
#!/bin/bash

data=$(ls -trh $1)
for entry in ${data}
do
  echo ${entry}
done
```

Can anyone help me to solve this ..

When i gave quotes like this myscript.sh 'E*' it worked fine , is there any way to do this without giving quotes ?

Comment: But i need to get the custom wilcard ..

Comment: why exactly are the quotes a problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### This is a shell expansion problem.

Your shell will interpret wildcard characters before passing then to your process. For example:

**script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1 $2 $3
```

Running the above with a wildcard:

```
> ./script.sh E*
Eva   Eve   Evolve
```

If you want to pass an argument without shell interpreting it first, you will have to quote it:

```
> ./script.sh 'E*'
E*
```

### Better Solution using `find`:

What you're actually trying to do is get a list of all files and folders in a given directory, in reverse modification time order (oldest first). The output of `ls` is notoriously painful to parse. It is preferable to use the powerful and flexible `find` command instead.

This is a one liner:

```
>  find ./ -maxdepth 1 -printf "%A@ %f\0" | sort -z -n | while read -d '' date line; do echo "$line"; done
```

Which is probably cryptic, but makes sense once explained.

- Find all files in this directory without recursing `find ./ -maxdepth 1`
- For each file, print out their last modified time in second `-printf "%A@`
- and their filename, separated by null characters  `%f\0"`
- Sort the null-separated strings by last modified time (numerically) `sort -z -n`
- For every null separated string assign the timestamp to 'date' and the rest of the line to 'line': `while read -d '' date line`
- Print the line `echo "$line"`

For example, in my directory:

```
> ls -l
total 4296
drwxr-xr-x 2 bfer cvs    4096 2012-03-05 15:49 colortry
drwxr-xr-x 3 bfer cvs    4096 2012-03-27 15:05 githug
drwxr-xr-x 3 bfer cvs    4096 2012-03-12 17:18 hooks-bare
drwxr-xr-x 3 bfer cvs    4096 2012-03-28 12:38 java
-rw-r--r-- 1 bfer cvs 4025413 2012-03-27 12:53 mozdebug
drwxr-xr-x 2 bfer cvs    4096 2012-02-16 12:54 mustache_bug_demo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 bfer cvs     113 2012-03-30 12:20 try.sh
> find ./ -maxdepth 1 -printf "%A@ %f\0" | sort -z -n | while read -d '' date line; do echo "$line"; done
mozdebug
colortry
hooks-bare
mustache_bug_demo
githug
java
try.sh
./
```

If you don't want the `./` result, just take it out of your final set.

> **updated:** With Sorpigal's suggestion to handle filenames with newlines.

### Further note on shell expansion

This is the same with things like parenthesis and ampersands. For example, the following curl commands will not work as expected:

```
> curl example.com/site?q=hello&name=bob
> echo 23/(7/98) | bc
```

As the ampersand and parentheses will be interpreted by the shell before they are passed to the process as arguments.

For this to work correctly, you will have to quote the args:

```
> curl "example.com/site?q=hello&name=bob"
> echo "23/(7/98)" | bc
```

Comment: The find example is good but still breaks on filenames with newlines. Null should be used as the delimiter to avoid this problem (that is, use `\0` instead of `\n` for `find -printf` and `-z` for `sort`.

Comment: Works as expected here with a file that has a blank. It comes up on its own line without splitting the filename.

Comment: Spaces would not cause a problem, but newlines would. Newline characters can be legally embedded in file names.

Comment: Apologies, should have read that more attentively. thanks for the warning. will change to reflect

Answer (score 2):

Did you enclose your wildcard when calling your script?

```
bash yourscript.sh 'E*'
```

Otherwise your script will get things that start with E in your current directory and $1 becomes exactly the first file, thus the behavior

Comment: when i did exx.sh 'E*' it worked , is there any way to do it without giving quotes ?

Comment: no as far as I know, as * is shell meta character and are expanded on invokation time, even your script doesn't know that it has been passed a '*' if you don't give it quotes.

Answer (score 2):

This sound like a Shell Expansion problem . If you want to pass wild card to a shell , just quote it . eg .

```
./script "E*"
```

Quoting would avoid shell expansion .

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using `ls` in a shell script. The output of `ls` is for human consumption *only* and should never be used as the input to another command.

First, the correct solution to your problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
pat="$1"
while IFS= read -r -d '' file ; do
    echo "$file"
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "$pat" -print0)
```

This presumes that you don't have any special ordering or name format requirements. You can refer to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22674/shell-script-for-moving-oldest-files/29205#29205) if you need ordering like `ls -t`.

Your problem is common and I call it the "Who sees what?" problem. You say `myscript.sh E*` and expect a literal `E*` to be passed to your script, but in fact since this argument is unquoted the [glob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) will be expanded by `bash` before your script is called, so what your script sees is all files in the current directory whose names started with `E`.

As you note, single-quoting the argument "fixes" this. This is because `bash` doesn't perform any special expansion inside single quotes, so now your script sees `E*` literally. You have, effectively, escaped the `*` so `bash` won't expand it before passing it to your script. To do this without using quotes is possible by backslash-escape the `*`

```
myscript.sh E\*
```

But a superior solution is to allow `bash` to expand the glob and change your script to handle processing multiple file arguments instead. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

data=("$(ls -trh "$@")")
for entry in "${data[@]}"
do
  echo "${entry}"
done
```

Here I assume that all arguments will be file names. I have changed `data` into an array and added quotes to all expansions, to preserve whitespace properly. This solution is still wrong, because it parses `ls` output, but now you probably get the behavior you expect out of the unquoted `E*`

```
myscript.sh E*
```

In general you should **always** quote the expansion of variables in shell scripts, because that probably does what you expect (and unquoted expansion probably does *not*!)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example:

> find files of a directory ordered by their modification dates from older to newer but less than or equal a given date and containing a '.inc' in their names

```
"find-files.sh"
#!/bin/bash
store=$1
date_given=$2
inc_files=()
limit=$( date +"%s" -d "$date_given" )
while read -r -d $'\0' seconds file; do
   seconds=${seconds%.*}
   if [[ $seconds -le $limit ]]; then
      printf "seconds=$seconds, file=$file\n"
      #block word splitting
      inc_files=( "${inc_files[@]}" "$file" )
      #do whatever you want here...
   fi
done < <(find $store -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.inc*" -printf "%T@ %f\0" | sort -zn)
```

and call it:

```
./find-files.sh '/a/dir/to/search' '2013-01-12 18:12:09'
```

I agree with @Sorpigal https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22674/shell-script-for-moving-oldest-files/29205#29205 it's very helpful except 'IFS=' in while loop that breaks everything in my system (Ubuntu).

Answer (score -3):

Try this.

```
#!/bin/bash
data=$(ls -trh "$@" | cat -E)
while [ ${#data} != 0 ]
do
  echo ${data%%\$*}
  data=${data#*\$}
done
```

Comment: that will resolve to `ls -trh Eva  Eve  Evolve ...`. In that case the `ls` is completely superfluous and you might as well write `for entry in $@`

Comment: you probably didn't notice the edit and it doesn't expand with the quotes and can handle file names with embedded blanks. It works fine.

Comment: No, it doesn't handle filenames with spaces. `for i in "$@"` _does_ handle them correctly.

Comment: It does :) Removed Downvote. It's a complex way of doing it though, and you still run into problems when you have subdirs. Hmmm. I think the solution might be to use find somehow...

Comment: Instead of using "$@", I use ls -trh to maintain the order of the output the poster intended.

Comment: Using `$`-delimited strings where you should use arrays? That's a downvote.